# How to fix this Matchmaking Rule set for AWS Game Lift

Tags: amazon-gamelift

I am new to Game Lift and am trying to make a ruleset for a Jeopardy game for a project I am creating. I try to apply what I want to do for the match making but I always seem to get this error and cannot figure out for the life of me what is wrong.

I am doing 3 players, each having near the same skill set so to keep it fair. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

I have already looked up all around the documentation of Game lift but I am still confused how this portion works. The examples they gave worked and I tried editing them to my own liking but it seems it did not work.

```
    "name": "Normal_Game",
    "ruleLanguageVersion": "1.0",
    "playerAttributes": [{
        "name": "skill",
        "type": "number",
        "default": 10
    }],
    "teams": [{
        "name": "red",
        "maxPlayers": 1,
        "minPlayers": 1
    }, {
        "name": "blue",
        "maxPlayers": 1,
        "minPlayers": 1
    },{
       "name": "green",
       "maxPlayers": 1,
       "minPlayers":1
}],
    "rules": [{
        "name": "FairTeamSkill",
        "description": "The average skill of players in each team is within 10 points from the average skill of all players in the match",
        "type": "distance",
        // get skill values for players in each team and average separately to produce list of two numbers
        "measurements": [ "avg(teams[*].players.attributes[skill])" ],
        // get skill values for players in each team, flatten into a single list, and average to produce an overall average
        "referenceValue": "avg(flatten(teams[*].players.attributes[skill]))",
        "maxDistance": 10 // minDistance would achieve the opposite result
    }, {
        "name": "EqualTeamSizes",
        "description": "Only launch a game when the number of players in each team matches, e.g. 4v4, 5v5, 6v6, 7v7, 8v8",
        "type": "comparison",
        "measurements": [ "count(teams[red].players)" ],
        "referenceValue": "count(teams[blue].players)",
        "operation": "=" // other operations: !=, <, <=, >, >=
        "referenceValue": "count(teams[green].players)",
        "operation": "="
    }],
    "expansions": [{
        "target": "rules[FairTeamSkill].maxDistance",
        "steps": [{
            "waitTimeSeconds": 5,
            "value": 50
        }, {
            "waitTimeSeconds": 15,
            "value": 100
        }]
    }]
}
```

I validate it all the time, expecting it to take it but it doesn't my error messages keep occurring  as this:

```
Rule set*
Encountered JSON parsing error: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries at [Source: { "name": "Normal_Game", "ruleLanguageVersion": "1.0", "playerAttributes": [{ "name": "skill", "type": "number", "default": 10 }], "teams": [{ "name": "red", "maxPlayers": 1, "minPlayers": 1 }, { "name": "blue", "maxPlayers": 1, "minPlayers": 1 },{ "name": "green", "maxPlayers": 1, "minPlayers":1 }], "rules": [{ "name": "FairTeamSkill", "description": "The average skill of players in each team is within 10 points from the average skill of all players in the match", "type": "distance", // get skill values for players in each team and average separately to produce list of two numbers "measurements": [ "avg(teams[*].players.attributes[skill])" ], // get skill values for players in each team, flatten into a single list, and average to produce an overall average "referenceValue": "avg(flatten(teams[*].players.attributes[skill]))", "maxDistance": 10 // minDistance would achieve the opposite result }, { "name": "EqualTeamSizes", "description": "Only launch a game when the number of players in each team matches, e.g. 4v4, 5v5, 6v6, 7v7, 8v8", "type": "comparison", "measurements": [ "count(teams[red].players)" ], "referenceValue": "count(teams[blue].players)", "operation": "=" // other operations: !=, <, <=, >, >= "referenceValue": "count(teams[green].players)", "operation": "=" }], "expansions": [{ "target": "rules[FairTeamSkill].maxDistance", "steps": [{ "waitTimeSeconds": 5, "value": 50 }, { "waitTimeSeconds": 15, "value": 100 }] }] }; line: 38, column: 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have these 2:

```
"referenceValue": 
"operation":
```

defined twice in `EqualTeamSizes` rules, that might cause issues. And a missing comma after `"operation": "="`

```
{
        "name": "EqualTeamSizes",
        "description": "Only launch a game when the number of players in each team matches, e.g. 4v4, 5v5, 6v6, 7v7, 8v8",
        "type": "comparison",
        "measurements": [ "count(teams[red].players)" ],
        "referenceValue": "count(teams[blue].players)",
        "operation": "=" // other operations: !=, <, <=, >, >=
        "referenceValue": "count(teams[green].players)",
        "operation": "="
    }
```